# How to handle quotes, backtick special characters for running linux bash shell command in remote server

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ansible, sh

Someone, please help me in correcting below command I wasted more than a day fixing below but failed, please help, I will be using below in ansible shell module.

```
 ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 splunk@10.145.32.172 '
     sdline="`
           grep -n TA-aws-hf-{{client_code}}-{{env_name}} /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf
          | awk -F \":\" \'{print $1}\'
         ` 
         && sed -ie \"$sdline,`
              echo $sdline + 3 
              | bc
         `d\"  /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf
     " 
> ^C
```

**Even tried below way:**

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 splunk@10.145.32.172 exec sdline=`grep -n TA-aws-hf-{{client_code}}-{{env_name}} /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf|awk -F ":" '{print $1}'` && sed -ie "$sdline,`echo $sdline + 3|bc` d"  /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf
grep: /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf: No such file or directory
bash: line 0: exec: sdline=: not found
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the three lines after and including the `TA-aws-hf-...-...` line from your serverclass.conf file?

Comment: Yes @vintnes , help me if you have a alternate solution for same.

Comment: While I work on this, please edit your question to describe that exact problem, including real input (serverclass.conf) and exact expected output.

Comment: Note that the old backpacks and `$( )` are expanded, when unquoted or inside double quotes, by the local shell before the command is executed.

Comment: @cdarke please help in correcting my command

Comment: @sudhirtataraju - you have not given a specification of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Context: It seems this question originated as an [XY Problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). OP appears to want to remove the 3 lines including and after the string "TA-aws-hf-{{client_code}}-{{env_name}}".

---

Backticks are deprecated; use `$(modern $(command) substitution)` when necessary. It is not necessary in this case.

If your remote server has GNU sed:

```
ssh splunk@10.145.32.172 'sed -i "/TA-aws-hf-{{client_code}}-{{env_name}}/,+2d" /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf'
```

If that gives you `sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unexpected ','`:

```
ssh splunk@10.145.32.172 '
  cd /opt/splunk/etc/system/local
  awk "/TA-aws-hf-{{client_code}}-{{/ {i=-3} i++>0" \
    serverclass.conf > temp && mv $_ serverclass.conf
'
```

Comment: no luck @vintnes ssh -o ConnectTimeout=5 splunk@10.145.32.172 'sdline="$(grep -n TA-aws-hf-{{client_code}}-{{env_name}} /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf|awk -F \":\" \'{print $1}\')" && sed -ie "$sdline,$(echo $sdline + 3|bc) d"  /opt/splunk/etc/system/local/serverclass.conf'
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: `$( )` are hardly modern, early 1990s at least.  See also  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated

Comment: `$(...)` is *preferred*, but backticks have never been deprecated (which would be a formally announced decision to remove support from a future version).

Comment: Use `&&` to prevent `mv` from overwriting `serverclass.conf` with an empty or partial `temp` file in the event `awk` does not succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Your remote command is quite complicated.

I suggest the following:

1. Use `ssh` to gain interactive shell in `10.145.32.172`
2. Create a script on `10.145.32.172` that do the work, with everything hard coded.
3. Refactor command line parameters to your script.
4. Call your script remotely from your local machine.

This strategy simplify the script and its maintenance. Allowing you to send only the important parameters.

If you have to deploy the script on many remote machines. Use shared storage resources, like NFS. Optionally copy the script using `scp` prior to running it.